# Eclipse cannot display contents of any file

Tags: eclipse

Today I encounter a problem about Eclipse. It cannot display contents of any file! This is illustrated by the following link of an image. Sorry, I cannot post image.

http://i.imgur.com/rC7pRNf.png?1

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro Preview. The version of Eclipse is Kepler and its build id is 20130614-0229.

Thanks a lot for any help!

UPDATE 1: I re-download eclipse and it is working! But I hope that someone can tell me why！

UPDATE 2： I have solved this problem. It involves font in Windows. I am using the `DejaVuSansMono` font. And I have installed it but I can't see it in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder (I have checked `Show hidden files,folders,and drivers` and unchecked `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` in the `Folder Option`). However, I can select it in Eclipse and when I use this font, the text using it displays nothing. Here is my solution.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwg5MQT4nJMIUmlCQjROem1hczQ/edit?usp=sharing

Hope that might help! Thanks for all the people who helped me!

Comment: Image cannot be viewd ..

Comment: I recommend Notepad++.

Comment: Where is the code ? How you trying to access this file ? Try `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Demo2.class.getResourceAsStream("fileName.extension")))` :-) Hope that might help :-)

Comment: No! The content of these files is existing. I can open them using another text editor and it can display their contents.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run eclipse in clean mode
2. Check eclipse error log (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, type "error log")
3. Check file associations

Comment: @user2849366 "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items cannot be found."

Comment: @Hot Licks This log info isn't related to the problem I said. It logs that I failed to install Apache Directory Studio yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the Apache Directory Studio install added some editor filters that crashed (threw exceptions) when you tried to open the files. This could be because of a version incompatibility, or because the install was corrupted.  It's incredibly hard to tell from your description, but that has happened to me in the pasts with other tools. The only way to fix that is to uninstall the broken plugins.

Comment: Can you tell me some concrete steps about how to uninstall the broken plugins in Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: Help-> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software. If the plugins are not in that list, you can remove the jar files from the <eclipse home>/plugins directory. Identifying the plugins is the hardest part.